when upgrading to angular 18, i get : While resolving: angularx-qrcode@17.0.1 => Found: @angular/core@18.1.0
when i use the ng update:
We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!
but still when i use npm i i get this:

I tried fixing it but nothing works.. dont know how to solve this. tbh i have no clue on how to fixe this.
these are the deps i have now:
 "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.1.0",
    "@capacitor-mlkit/barcode-scanning": "^5.3.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.4.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/app-launcher": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.7.4",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^5.4.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/share": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol": "^2.1.2",
    "@solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol-web3js": "^2.1.2",
    "@solana/pay": "^0.2.5",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.3",
    "@solana/spl-token-registry": "^0.2.4574",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.91.1",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^17.0.1",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bs58": "^5.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "expo-linking": "^6.0.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "nanoid": "^5.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "tweetnacl": "^1.0.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.6"
  },


try to remove the library from package.json:
and then run npm install again, and then install it back:
npm i angularx-qrcode
Helps almost always. Especially true that you are not upgrading: you have mismatch of versions in package.json

its giving even more dep issues with es-lint when i try? this is messed up...

I recommend you remove and then install one by one. But you can always use --force or --legacy-peer-deps as the error suggests. It may be easier, since your package.json really looks very strange
